# istio-ingress v.s. nginx-ingress, which shoud be used?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, nginx-ingress

Here is a question about kubernetes ingerss.

Say that new services are frequently added to a cluster, and routing rules are then reqiured to be added frequently.

For example, every 0.1s a new service named `{UUID}WorkerSvc` is created and thus I would need to add a routing rules `Host: {UUID}WorkerSvc.example.com -> Service: {UUID}WorkerSvc` for it.

I wonder which would be a optimal sollution for that? (which one can guarantee existing connections from client to previous services)

1. (using nginx-ingress)Every 0.1s, to create a new nginx ingress resource as `Host: {UUID}WorkerSvc.example.com -> Service: {UUID}WorkerSvc`.

   I've noticed that each time new `path` is added within an ingress, nginx instance would require a `reload`, which possibly cause existing connections to fail.
2. (using istio)Every 0.1s, to create a istio virtual service as `Host: {UUID}WorkerSvc.example.com -> Service: {UUID}WorkerSvc`

   (I know little about it, but I think that adding virtual service to istio would result in pilot reconfiguration)

Comment: "which possibly cause existing connections to fail." --- it won't

Comment: @zerkms This [article](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/dynamically-update-routing-configurations-through-alibaba-cloud-k8s-ingress-controller_594929) describles this possiblity of fails because of the EPOLL multi-process mode using by Nginx, especially "Persistent connection services are frequently disconnected."

Comment: They are disconnected not because of an accident but because it was taken longer than `worker-shutdown-timeout`. You can set it to whatever value you like, the default is 4 minutes.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you. So it seems the only drawback here is that it "may cause certain QPS jitter and access failures, and cause a large number of Nginx Worker processes to be in a shutting-down status, resulting in memory bloat".

Comment: I would try to investigate whether switching to "istio virtual service" implementation could avoid such drawbacks.